# Актуальность изучения GWT

Tags: gwt

Недавно прочитал, что Google собирается создавать новый язык для веба Google Dart (Dash) как замену JavaScript. Если этот проект пойдет нормально, будет ли смысл Гуглу развивать Google Web Toolkit? Как вы думаете, Дарт вытеснит GWT или GWT всё равно будет актуален?

Comment:    Еще  надо  чтобы  остальные  разработчики  вэб-браузеров  согласились  втыкать  это  к себе   в  свои  продукты

Comment: Опыт всегда актуален.

Comment: Привет из 16-то года. Dart не взлетел (

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Полностью согласен. Зато как болезненно реагируют на критику - "мол, а что Вы хотели, думали это для Вас инженеры Google старались. Нет, не для всех они это делали, для себя, для внутренних целей его разрабатывали". Мы (так тихонько) - "Так вроде бы наобещали нам с три короба? Иль нет?". Они (так грозно) - "На чужой каравай рот не разевай. Не потому мы пятилетку батрачили чтобы всякие холопы на наше добро зарились".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл GWT - создать условия, когда Java становится ЕДИНЫМ языком программирования для сервера и клиента. Программисты, знающие Java, могут, не изучая еще один язык, использовать GWT для программирования веб-приложений. GWT самостоятельно оттранслирует Java-код в JavaScript, или в тот же Dart, при условии, что последний и правда будет работать на стороне браузера. Один язык разработки и одна кодовая база значительно облегчают процесс разработки и последующей поддержки. До тех пор, пока будут находиться желающие использовать такой подход, GWT будет актуален. Независимо от того, какой язык будет принят на стороне клиента - JavaScript или что-то еще.

Другое дело, что у GWT есть свои недостатки, не связанные с Dart и/или JavaScript. GWT со временем, подобно стеку Java EE, стал чрезмерно усложненной технологией. Впрочем, для многих этот тезис спорен. Если что и способно убить технологию, так это постепенное понижение ее эргономичности для пользователя, в данном случае - программиста. При условии, конечно, что найдутся более удобные, эффективные и надежные альтернативы.

Comment: SmartGWT меня просто очаровал (в смысле графики, доступной из нормального языка в окне браузера).